# replace substring in lines using sed or grep

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I have a file with a lot of lines, two of them are:

```
videoId: 'S2Rgr6yuuXQ'

var vid_seq=1;
```

in a shell script, I have two variables, 
for id, the value is always 11 characters/numbers

id='fsafsferii2'

id_seq=80

I want to modify these two lines with id and id_seq

```
videoId: 'fsafsferii2'

var vid_seq=80;
```

I used

```
sed -i 's/\(videoId: \).*\\1'${id}'/\2' file
```

but there are errors, what is wrong with my script?

thanks

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Right.  You're using a `/` as a delimiter for your substitution.  The command is `s/pattern/replacement/` and you're missing the final delimiter.  That's what "unterminated" means.

Comment: even I add /, it is still wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grep` command won't "replace" text, it is for "global regular expression print".  But sed will.

```
sed -i'' '/^videoId: /s/: .*/: '"$id"'/;/^var vid_seq=/s/=.*/='"$id_seq"';/'
```

I'm not a big fan of inserting variables into sed scripts this way, but sed is simple, and provides no mechanism for actually using actual variables on its own.  If you're going to do this, include some format checking for the two variables to make sure they contain the data you want them to contain, before you run this sed script.  An accidental `/` in a variable would cause the sed script to fail.

**UPDATE** per comments:

Here's a successful test:

```
$ id=fsafsferii2
$ id_seq=80
$ cat inp686

videoId: 'S2Rgr6yuuXQ'

var vid_seq=1;

$ sed '/^videoId: /s/: .*/: '"$id"'/;/^var vid_seq=/s/=.*/='"$id_seq"';/' < inp686

videoId: fsafsferii2

var vid_seq=80;

$
```

Of course, you'll need to do some quote magic to get the single quotes into your videoId, but I'm sure you can figure that out yourself.

**UPDATE 2**

According to sed's man page, the substitute command is in the form:

```
     [2addr]s/regular expression/replacement/flags
```

The `[2addr]` means you can specify up to two "addresses", which can be line numbers or regular expressions to match.  So the `s` (substitute) command can take a line, a range, a match, or a span between matches.  In our case, we're just using a single match to identify what lines we want to execute the substitution on.

The script above is made up of two sed commands, separated by a semicolon.

- `/^videoId: /` -- Match lines that start with the word `videoId:`...

  - `s/: .*/: '"$id"'/;` -- Substitute all text from the colon to the end of the line with whatever is in the `$id` environment variable.
- `/^var vid_seq=/` -- Match lines that ... meh, as above.

  - `s/=.*/='"$id_seq"';/` -- Substitute all text from the equals sign on with `$id_seq`.

Note that the `'"$id"'` construct means that we are *exiting* the single quotes, then immediately *entering* double quotes for the expansion of the variable ... then exiting the double quotes and going back into a new set of single quotes.  Sed scripts are safest inside single quotes because of the frequent use of characters that might be interpreted by a shell.

Note also that because sed's substitute command uses a forward slash as a delimiter, the `$id` and `$id_seq` variables may not contain a slash.  If they might, you can switch to a different delimiter.

Comment: Works for me in the test environment I created based on your question.  If you have tried it and get a different error, then [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13288963/edit) and show the results.  Don't forget to show your actual variables. If I can't reproduce your error, I can't fix it.

Comment: ah, I modified ^ -> .* coz before videoId, there are many null characters, it OK now. BTW, can you explain the script a bit

Comment: @user1769686 - added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with:

```
sed -i 's/\(videoId: \).*\\1'${id}'/\2' file
```

1. Missing the third delimiter (`/`). Valid syntax is `s/regex/replace/`
2. Incorrect regex pattern (let's assume `${id}` has been substituted)

   ```
   \(videoId: \).*\\1fsafsferii2
   ```

   is telling it to match a string that looks like this:

   ```
   videoId: anything\1fsafsferii2
   ```

   (`\\` in regex matches literal backslash, so `\\1` would match a literal backslash followed by `1` instead of 1st sub-expression)
3. Replace the matched string with `\2`

   But since there is only one set of parentheses, `\2` is actually empty.

   Also, since the regex pattern in 2. doesn't match anything, nothing is replaced.

---

This should work (GNU sed)

```
sed -i 's/\(videoId: \).*/\1 \x27'${id}'\x27/
        s/\(var vid_seq=\).*/\1'${id_seq}'\;/' file
```

Note:

- `\x27` is the hexadecimal representation of single quote (to prevent clashing with the other single quote)
- `\;` for literal semicolon. If `;` is not escaped, it's interpreted to terminate the `s` command in `sed`.

Comment: `\x27` doesn't work for me.  When I `echo hello | sed 's/e/\x26/'`, the result is `hx26llo`.

Comment: My guess is some older versions of sed don't support this hexadecimal notation.

Comment: This is the sed in FreeBSD 9.1-RC3.  I get the same behaviour in OSX Mountain Lion.  Perhaps you're running a non-standard sed.